# Fetch entities by count of his relationships, even if they haven't yet relation (ManyToMany) - Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I'm trying to fetch a collection of entities (which is named Animation) by its ManyToMany relation with another entity (which is named Tag).

Here is my Animation entity:

```
class Animation
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company\AppBundle\Entity\Tag",inversedBy="animations")
   */
   protected $tags;

}
```

And my Tag Entity:

```
class Tag 
{
  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company\AppBundle\Entity\Animation", mappedBy="tags")
  * @ORM\JoinTable(name="animation_tag")
  */
  protected $animations;
}
```

I just want to fetch Animations which have less than 3 Tags linked, even if no Tag is already linked to them.

I created a "findAnimsByTag()" method in my AnimationRepository in using Doctrine Query Builder which is as below:

```
public function findAnimsByTag() {

    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('a')
    ->from('CompanyAppBundle:Animation', 'a')
    ->join('a.tags', 't')
    ->groupBy('t')
    ->having('COUNT(t) < 3 ')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult(); 
}
```

This query well fetch entities which haven't more than 3 Tags, but doesn't get entities which haven't yet relation (As explained at top of post).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use leftJoin instead join

```
 public function findAnimsByTag() {

    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('a')
    ->from('CompanyAppBundle:Animation', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('a.tags', 't')
    ->groupBy('t')
    ->having('COUNT(t) < 3 ')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
But I don't understand, now, assumed all my Animations entities haven't yet relations, the new query returns me only the first entity, instead of all my entities (Because no one has relations, the query should return me all of my table, not ?)